# Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch

Tags: java, spring

### spring code ##

```
@RequestMapping(value = "treeanatomy", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getTreeAnatomy(HttpServletRequest request, String treeAnatomyMap, int realm) {
        System.out.println("tree anatomy map in cms: " + treeAnatomyMap);
        com.google.gson.JsonParser udmJson = new com.google.gson.JsonParser();
        JsonElement surveyjson = udmJson.parse(treeAnatomyMap); 
        String wsId=surveyjson.getAsJsonObject().get("wsId").getAsString();
        String treeType=surveyjson.getAsJsonObject().get("treeType").getAsString();
        String langrealm=surveyjson.getAsJsonObject().get("langrealm").getAsString();
        String snapnode=null;
        if(surveyjson.getAsJsonObject().get("snapnode").getAsString().isEmpty()){
           snapnode=surveyjson.getAsJsonObject().get("snapnode").getAsString();
        }

        Map<String , Object> mytreeMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//      if (!isAuthenticated(id, jsessionId, Integer.valueOf(realm))) {
//          model.addAttribute("message", "You are not authorized to access this application");
//          return "home";
//      }
//      logger.info("Snapnode :" + snapnode +"   :   " + langrealm);
        Node rootNode;
        //model.addAttribute("userName", userSession.getUserName());

        TeneTree tree = treeUtils.getTree(wsId, realm);
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder=new GsonBuilder();
        gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    //  snapnode = "1397709503192";
        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(snapnode)) {
            rootNode = tree.getRootNode();
        } else {
            rootNode = tree.getNode(Long.valueOf(snapnode));
        }
        List<List<Node>> paths = treeUtils.getTreeAllPaths(rootNode,langrealm);
        System.out.println("size is.. "+paths.size());
        mytreeMap.put("paths", paths);  
        mytreeMap.put("treeId", wsId);
        mytreeMap.put("snapnode", snapnode);    
        return gson.toJson(mytreeMap);
    }
```

### Rest template

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "treeanatomy{treeType}-{wsId}-{langrealm}.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private ModelAndView returnTa(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String wsId, @PathVariable String treeType, @PathVariable String langrealm,
            @ModelAttribute("snapnode") String snapnode,String mAction){
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
        UserBean user = userService.getUserBean(authentication.getName());
        System.out.println("treeAnatomy post data : " );    
        Map<String,Object> taPostMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        taPostMap.put("wsId", wsId);
        taPostMap.put("treeType", treeType);
        taPostMap.put("langrealm", langrealm);
        taPostMap.put("snapnode", snapnode); 
        System.out.println("ta postmap data : " + taPostMap);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String adminResult = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8085/tenecms/cms/treeanatomy?treeAnatomyMap={taPostMap}&realm="+user.getRealmId(),
                String.class,gson.toJson(taPostMap));
        com.google.gson.JsonParser adminJson = new com.google.gson.JsonParser();
        JsonElement adminjson = adminJson.parse(adminResult);
        System.out.println("treeAnatomy post json data :" + adminjson);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        helper.updateCsrf(request, model);
        model.setViewName("ta/addTa");
        model.addObject("paths", adminjson.getAsJsonObject().get("paths"));
        model.addObject("treeId",adminjson.getAsJsonObject().get("treeId"));
        model.addObject("snapnode",adminjson.getAsJsonObject().get("snapnode"));
        model.addObject("mAction", mAction);
        return model;
    }
}
```

1. Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
root cause

org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 null
    org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:667)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:287)
    ssd.prod.nve.view.controllers.TreeAnatomyController.returnTa(TreeAnatomyController.java:52)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:122)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

2. List> paths = treeUtils.getTreeAllPaths(rootNode,langrealm); 
   // getting exception when i used this paths

Comment: do you also have a question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code to the end, Post you  exception as text, not as image, and specify your question. Perhaps just read this upfront: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yess i added code properly.

Comment: please provide me the solution, I am trying this from 15 days but getting the same exception. Thanks in advance.